# tuning neural network parameter

Tags: python, neural-network, regression

I'm testing a Self Organizing Map neural network algorithm to perform a model regression.

I performed a basic test in Python, with the somoclu toolbox (very efficient in computation time). I use a x² function as a test function. Then, I tried to create a SOM with 50x50 points. I have plotted a series of curves where you can see the original points vs SOM. The interpolation is not satisfaying for me because if I'm not learning enough, there are outliers, and if I'm learning too much, it is fitting with original points. What I would like is to have points between points of my square curve.

I understand that in this case outliers are not "stupid" because they try to connect points. But it can't be used in state as a model regression.

Can you explain to me where I'm wrong in my tuning parameters? Or how to remove outliers?

[image]

my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import somoclu
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('10_samples.txt', sep='\t', header = 0)
data = data.as_matrix()

epoch_size = np.linspace(2,100,99)

for j in epoch_size:
    som = somoclu.Somoclu(n_columns=50, n_rows=50, data=data, kerneltype = 0, initialization = 'pca')
    som.train(epochs=int(j))

    a=som.codebook
    dim=a.shape
    som_ncodebook = [[]]
    for i in range(dim[2]):
        param = a[:,:,i]
        param = param.reshape(1,dim[0]*dim[1]) # raboute ligne à ligne 
        param = param.reshape(dim[0]*dim[1],1) # transforme en colonne
        if i == 0 :
            som_ncodebook = param
        else:
            som_ncodebook=np.append(som_ncodebook,param,axis=1)

    codebookplot = som_ncodebook


    plt.plot(codebookplot[:,0],codebookplot[:,1],'ob')
    plt.plot(data[:,0],data[:,1],'.r')
    plt.title('codebook epoch = '+str(j))
    plt.savefig('test_'+str(int(j))+'.png')
    plt.close()
```